# Unity GUI not loading in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher, startup, gui

Due to Low charging my Laptop switched -off while executing 
'sudo apt-get upgrade' command.

After it I tried logging in after charging the Laptop, 
OS seems to Login after asking for password but Unity GUI does not load
It does not show sidebar, titlebar or any GUI elements on Screen

While right clicking the mouse I can access terminal I tried followig commands

```
sudo apt-get install unity-desktop
sudo apt-get install -reinstall unity-desktop
sudo reboot -h now
```

While these  did not work I installed gnome-desktop and It also failed 
I removed and purged it's dependencies.

I also tried

```
sudo dpkg configure -a 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

please suggest how to resolve the error.

Following Instructions in [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), did not work. GUI is not working

Comment: I would suggest checking your commands, and telling us which didn't work.  the --reinstall option requires two hyphens, I'm not familiar with the -h option for reboot but it makes me think of --halt (which would turn the machine off).  I wouldn't have done those things, but `fsck` (file system checked your disk/file-system), then `sudo apt upgrade` to try & continue upgrade that was stopped (not what you did; then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to ensure system was full-updated). fyi: GNOME desktop for 16.04 is EOL as only Unity has 5 years of support

Comment: I tried all the instructions  [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) and GUI did not work

Comment: I tried `sudo apt dist-upgrade` , it does not work